# Android app update release with 2 different aliases in the keystore

Tags: java, android, apk, keystore, android-keystore

I release Android apps to market via some distribution channel (not the PlayStore). I have uploaded version1 of the app signed with X.KeyStore. Later, by mistake I release a version2 of the app with Y.keystore. Now I want to release version3 which will update both version1 and version2 installs. Is there a way to combine these two keystores into one and release a version to let both the apps update? I know we can have 2 aliases in the same keystore. But it asks for one alias to be confirmed while signing. Please help with a possible work around.

Comment: Did you get any error prevent you to generate? Based on my understanding, there should be no issue using different aliases in the keystore

Comment: Yes. I was able to add multiple aliases in the same keystore. I have issues while trying to release a version to let both the old versions update, as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign with both keys, you have to do it in two operations, i.e. sign with first one, then sign with the second one.
However, this will not work on Android because the platform will only update an app if it's signed with the same list of certificates. You can try locally, and you should be faced with an error at installation time.